# How do I parallelise a basic fortran do loop using MPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, fortran77, do-loops

I am new to MPI. I have a fortran 77 program which reads in a large data file (~1.7 GB) and then does some analysis on the data. Then it reads in the next data file and does the analysis again. This process repeats itself 'nstep' times (where for me nstep ~=1000). 
I attach some relevant sections of the code. The analysis itself is not time consuming. The reading in of the large data files is time consuming.

Note MN is a Massive Number, the files I'm reading in typically have between 4 - 4.7 million lines (particles) i.e. integer 'i' changes at each step.

Currently reading in 1000 data files will take several hours on 1 core. I would like to parallelize the program below (do loop) so that each core can read in a smaller chunk of the data.

```
c *** DECLARATIONS ***    
     integer MN
     parameter (MN=4700000)
     ....etc
c ********************

c *** SELECT INPUT DATA STEP ***/
     open(10,file='../ini/ghofile.dat',status='old')
      do is=0,nstep-1
       read(10,*) step

     ...

c *** OPEN INPUT DATA FILE (THE DO LOOP BELOW IS TIME CONSUMING) ***/
     open(20,file=filename,status='old')

        do i=0,MN
         read(20,121,end=21) x(i),y(i),z(i),vx(i),vy(i),
    &                        vz(i),m(i).... etc
121      format(17(1pE13.5),2(I10),2(1pE13.5),I10)

        enddo
21      ns=i
        write(6,*) 'No of particles =',ns

      enddo
      close(20)

      stop
      end
```

Comment: Parallelising input is likely to lead to disappointment unless you have the hardware (and systems software) to support multiple processes simultaneously reading from either the same file or from a large file already split into chunks.  If you only have one drive head consider its activity when 2 (or more) processes simultaneously try to get access to different parts of the disk.

Comment: Well I have access to a cpu/gpu cluster with hundreds of cores and hundreds of TB hard disk space.... I guess I can also try parallelize so that each core does 1 step.... but I would have preferred to do it the original way.

Comment: If you do have the hardware to read a file or files in parallel, the next question is: *Is your computation embarrassingly parallel ?*  Your question doesn't make it clear that the computation of each step depends on the previous or other earlier steps.  Does it ?

Comment: Yes, this specific problem is embarrassingly parallel. The computation of each step is independent/does not depend on previous step.

Comment: Then you don't need to bother with MPI.  Just start N instances of the program, give each 1/N of the input to work on.  You can probably do this with a shell script.

Comment: Could you be more specific how to do this? Also whilst this specific problem right now is step independent, in the future it probably will not be, so I prefer to use MPI.

Comment: Step 1: use your favourite toolset (editor, `split`, ...) to divide your input file into `N` pieces.  Step2: log on to machine `1`, start your program, specify file piece 1 as the input. Step 3: log on to machine `2`, start your program, specify file piece 2 as the input. And so forth.  In practice, your cluster has probably got a resource / job management system (such as Grid Engine) which can take most of the pain out of doing this.  As for MPI, start working through a tutorial, there are several good ones on the net including this: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/